# HTML dropdown list with the ability to add a custom value in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu, angular

I have the following use case

We present a hardcoded dropdown list to the user

Eg: Dropdown list with 4 choices say apple, orange, grape, pineapple and 'write your own'

If the user does not like those 4 choices, he/she can select the 'write your own' option from the drop down. Now the user is shown an input box where he/she can write their own fruit like say 'banana'.

How can I implement this with Angular 2 new forms module?

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work for you

HTML:

```
    <select *ngIf="!showAdditional" [(ngModel)]="mySelect" name="mySelect" (ngModelChange)="custom()">
        <option *ngFor="let o of options" [value]="o">{{o}}</option>
    </select>
    <input *ngIf="showAdditional" type="text" [(ngModel)]="additionalOption" name="additionalOptions" />
```

Ts:

```
export class SomeComponent {
    mySelect: string; 
    options: string[] = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'write your own'];
    additionalOption: string;
    showAdditional: boolean = false;

    custom() {
        if (this.mySelect === 'write your own') this.showAdditional = true;
    }
}
```

So if the user wants to add a custom option you hide the select and show the input. You can add additional validation for angular 2 forms this is just the bare set up.